# read() write() integer value on client server using C

Tags: c, networking

I'm currently working on an implementation of client server.  I would like the client to send a single integer value i.e 23 using the write command to the server so the server can retrieve this value and store it in an integer variable for use later.  This is what I've tried so far but obviously its wrong.  Can anyone show me an easy way to do this?

client:

```
int nread = 23; //the value I want to write to server
write(sockfd, nread, 10); //sockfd is socket to server
```

server:

```
int fileSize[1]; //buffer for reading value into?
read(sock,*fileSize,10);
int value = fileSize[0]; //I want to store value here
```

Comment: @user3386109 I'd assume that this part is already solved and the actual issue is indeed only sending/receiving data.

Comment: Besides the fact that the size you pass does not correlate with what you send at all and assuming that socket setup and connect/accept is done properly, endianness and padding aren't an issue, then closely read the documentation for read()/write() and learn that those two functions (at least for sockets) do not necessarily read/wrtite as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data expected had been read/written is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/15746983

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `write()` will expect the address to whatever memory is going to be sent, so you can't just pass the number (your client code) or dereference an integer that's never been set (your server code). Also, is there any specific reason you're sending 10 bytes? That's really odd for an integer.

I'd try the following:

Client:

```
int nread = 23;
write(sockfd, &nread, sizeof(int)); // &nread returns the address to nread
write(sockfd, &nread, sizeof(nread)); // Alternative version always using the proper type
```

Server:

```
int value;
read(sock, &value, sizeof(int)); // &value returns the address to value
read(sock, &value, sizeof(value)); // Alternative version always using the proper type
```

However, keep in mind that this might have more issues, e.g. when considering a mix of little endian/big endian systems as well as systems with different lengths for `int`.

Comment: @Neel What do you want to do instead? Hardcode the length? If so, why? If you're mixing platforms, the code is most likely to break anyway, but at least you don't have to know the actual platform if you're using the same for client/server.

Comment: yes you are right and I don't want to write hardcoded length but cant I write sizeof(nread)) here?

Comment: @Neel Yes, of course. You could as well call `sizeof(variable)`. Just be careful if you're passing pointers rather than retrieving addresses within that line.